# How to synchronise HTTP calls and return a promise at the end?

Tags: angularjs

I have some Web API that return data.
Now I want to create a custom object based on such data.
The thing is that these http calls are dependent.
Here is the code, as you can see, at **getLabMainAndLinesCombined()** 
there are 4 http calls encapsulated in:

1. contactsService.getContactPersonsIdNameList()
2. getLabMainsIdAppIdList()
3. getAllLabLines()
4. getAllLabMains()

And lastly there is the **generateProperMappings** that 'glues' it up.

```
var generateProperMappings = function (companiesIdName, contactPersonsIdName, labMainsIdAppId, labMains, labLines) {
        var result = [];
        var i = 0;
        while (i < labMains.length) {
            var labMain = labMains[i];
            var workAppId = labMainsIdAppId.filter(options => options.id === labMain.id)[0].appId;
            var companyName = companiesIdName.filter(options => options.id === labMain.companyId)[0].name;
            var contactPersonName = contactPersonsIdName.filter(options => options.id === labMain.contactPersonId)[0].fullName;
            var associatedLabLines = labLines.filter(options => options.assignedToWork === labMain.id);
            var viewDetails = {
                work: { id: labMain.id, appId: workAppId },
                company: { id: labMain.companyId, name: companyName },
                contactPerson: { id: labMain.contactPersonId, fullName: contactPersonName },
                workDetails: { created: labMain.dateCreated },
                labLinesAssociated: associatedLabLines
            }
            result.push(viewDetails);
            i++;
        };
        return result;
    };

    var getLabMainAndLinesCombined = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        console.log("Generating view of mains and lines combined");
        var companiesIdName = [];
        var contactPersonsIdName = [];
        var labMainsIdAppId = [];
        var labLines = [];
        var labMains = [];
        var result = [];
        contactsService.getCompaniesIdNameList().then(data => {
            angular.copy(data, companiesIdName);
            contactsService.getContactPersonsIdNameList().then(data => {
                angular.copy(data, contactPersonsIdName);
                getLabMainsIdAppIdList().then(data => {
                    angular.copy(data, labMainsIdAppId);
                    getAllLabLines().then(data => {
                        angular.copy(data, labLines);
                        getAllLabMains().then(data => {
                            angular.copy(data, labMains);
                            result.push(generateProperMappings(companiesIdName, contactPersonsIdName, labMainsIdAppId, labMains, labLines));
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        deferred.resolve(result);
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

The problem is that this function (a Service function) is called from a controller, but the result data is returned before it is really generated...
Here is the call:

```
var onLabLinesReceived = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    angular.copy(data, vm.labLines);
}
labService.getLabMainAndLinesCombined().then(onLabLinesReceived, onError).finally(function () { vm.isBusy -= 1 });
```

In the debugging @ Chrome, it looks like this:

labService.js:53 Generating view of mains and lines combined contactsService.js:27 Getting all companies id name list labLinesTableController.js:35 [] <-- PROBLEM contactsService.js:36 Getting all contacts id name list labService.js:15 Getting all lab mains labService.js:7 Getting all lab lines labService.js:15 Getting all lab mains

Comment: there are independent calls. Use $q.all()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return the promise from `getLabMainAndLinesCombined` function

```
var getLabMainAndLinesCombined = function () {
   console.log("Generating view of mains and lines combined");
    var companiesIdName = [];
    var contactPersonsIdName = [];
    var labMainsIdAppId = [];
    var labLines = [];
    var labMains = [];
    var result = [];
    return contactsService.getCompaniesIdNameList().then(data => {
        angular.copy(data, companiesIdName);
        contactsService.getContactPersonsIdNameList().then(data => {
            angular.copy(data, contactPersonsIdName);
            getLabMainsIdAppIdList().then(data => {
                angular.copy(data, labMainsIdAppId);
                getAllLabLines().then(data => {
                    angular.copy(data, labLines);
                    getAllLabMains().then(data => {
                        angular.copy(data, labMains);
                        result.push(generateProperMappings(companiesIdName, contactPersonsIdName, labMainsIdAppId, labMains, labLines));

                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't resolve your promise until after all of the items you need have been added to results function has finished. Right now what you're code is doing is sending a promise that resolves to an empty list.

```
var getLabMainAndLinesCombined = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    console.log("Generating view of mains and lines combined");
    var companiesIdName = [];
    var contactPersonsIdName = [];
    var labMainsIdAppId = [];
    var labLines = [];
    var labMains = [];
    var result = [];
    contactsService.getCompaniesIdNameList().then(data => {
        angular.copy(data, companiesIdName);
        contactsService.getContactPersonsIdNameList().then(data => {
            angular.copy(data, contactPersonsIdName);
            getLabMainsIdAppIdList().then(data => {
                angular.copy(data, labMainsIdAppId);
                getAllLabLines().then(data => {
                    angular.copy(data, labLines);
                    getAllLabMains().then(data => {
                        angular.copy(data, labMains);
                        result.push(generateProperMappings(companiesIdName, contactPersonsIdName, labMainsIdAppId, labMains, labLines));
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    })
    // Resolve your promise here after all the data has been retrieved.
    .then(() => {deferred.resolve(result)});

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

I'd strongly recommend you refactor your code for readability.

```
var getLabMainAndLinesCombined = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    console.log("Generating view of mains and lines combined");
    var companiesIdName = [];
    var contactPersonsIdName = [];
    var labMainsIdAppId = [];
    var labLines = [];
    var labMains = [];
    var result = [];

    // You can use hanging indentation and have then statements return
    // The promises they are meant to sequentially resolve. That way
    // the code is much more readable and gives a clearer picture of 
    // how the function works. 
    contactsService.getCompaniesIdNameList()
        .then(data => {
            angular.copy(data, companiesIdName);
            return contactsService.getContactPersonsIdNameList()
        })
        .then(data => {
            angular.copy(data, contactPersonsIdName);
            return getLabMainsIdAppIdList();
        })
        .then(data => {
            angular.copy(data, labMainsIdAppId);
            return getAllLabLines()
        })
        .then(data => {
            angular.copy(data, labLines);
            return getAllLabMains();
        })
        .then(data => {
            angular.copy(data, labMains);
            result.push(generateProperMappings(companiesIdName, contactPersonsIdName, labMainsIdAppId, labMains, labLines));
        })
        // Now when promise is complete it will renturn the list
        .then(() => { deferred.promise; }); 

};
```